# How to implement the merge view or diff view with codemirror 6

Tags: javascript, codemirror, codemirror-6

with codemirror version 5.x we have a demo for merge view on the website but I wanted the same feature with the code mirror version 6. any suggestion on how to achieve it. similar to this https://codemirror.net/5/demo/merge.html

[image]

Comment: its version 6 of code mirror

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  please find attachment.

Comment: Iif this is an official example, you probably want to ask over on https://github.com/codemirror/dev/issues (if it's not already mentioned somewhere in there).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Do you mean still this doesn't release.?

Comment: it does, but apparently the way it gets released completely changed (with a new repo, which doesn't have v6 tagged releases)